# How can I update PHP 5.16 to 5.2.* on a Centos VPS

Tags: php, centos, update

I am buying a new VPS with CentOS and I need to upgrade my PHP to 5.2.*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to grab the packages from CentOS's 'Testing' repository, instructions are on the CentOS wiki, here: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PHP_5.1_To_5.2

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use http://iuscommunity.org/packages/ which allows you to install via a package name php52.